# Customise maven checkstyle plugin

Tags: java, maven, customization, checkstyle

I'm trying to create custom checkstyle. Already have [SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/novoda/novoda-checkstyle-checks/1.0-SNAPSHOT/) on sonatype however the test project where I'm trying to test it on is not able to pull depencency. Error is

```
[INFO] Building TestProject 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10:checkstyle (default-cli) @ TestProject ---
Downloading: http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/com/novoda/novoda-checkstyle-checks/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/com/novoda/novoda-checkstyle-checks/1.0-SNAPSHOT/novoda-checkstyle-checks-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.novoda:novoda-checkstyle-checks:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/com/novoda/novoda-checkstyle-checks/1.0-SNAPSHOT/novoda-checkstyle-checks-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.993s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 08 16:37:42 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10:checkstyle (default-cli) on project TestProject: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10:checkstyle failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.novoda:novoda-checkstyle-checks:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots) -> [Help 1]
```

Here is project pom

```
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <properties>
    <checkstyle.config.location>properties/checkstyle-configuration.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.novoda</groupId>
            <artifactId>novoda-checkstyle-checks</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Any idea why dependency plugin is not downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException) is simple. Since it is plugin that I'm trying to fetch I need to use `pluginRepositories` instead of `repositories`

```
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: I faced same issue running a build on gitlab saas after migrating an existing on-prem project and yes that was because i forgot to configure plugin repositories too. Thanks for the answer, definitely saved my time

Answer (score 0):

You can see that maven is looking for the snapshot in the wrong repo `http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/`
Your artifact is in `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots`

Either the pom you are using to run is not the one that defines the sonatype `<repository>` or it is being overwriten. Check the effective pom in the folder where you run maven and find the  definition, you will probably find it is apache.org and not sonatype's

Alternatively, it is usually not recommended to use `<repository>` in your poms since it makes the artifacts unusable by others that don't have access to the special repo, check [this article](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/). I prefer configuring the custom repo (sonatype snapshots) in *settings.xml*